# How does Jedi order finance itself?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

There are numerous examples in all levels of canon of Jedi being pretty well funded. They run the Order; own starfighters; they send out intergalactic expeditions; they own some prime real estate; etc...

So how do they get funded to afford all that? They are warrior monks, and don't have access to the typical funding sources of religious orders (tithes from population, grants from nobles, selling things that monks produce, looting their enemies like Tampliers).

Is the Republic funding them?

Comment: Didn't they fund themselves by selling blockbuster movies?

Comment: @Blackwood - I don't recall busting blocks being one of canon Jedi Force Powers

Comment: @obie don't think so.  1.  That question is about Jedi as individuals,  this is about Order as organization.  2. That question is about morality/rules,  this one is about finance